# Laravel Query builder - query not working but works in SQL console

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I've become extremely confused I'm trying to run a query through laravels query builder which should work but it's throwing odd errors.

I'm trying to count records from the tips table where the status is 'Won' between a daterange and then join the users table on the user_id to retrieve the users username.

This is my query builder

```
    $topfiveTipsters = DB::table('tips')
      ->select(DB::raw('count(status) as wincount, users.name'))
      ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'tips.user_id')
      ->whereBetween('tips.created_at',[$start,$end])
      ->where('status','Won')
      ->groupBy('users.id')
      ->orderBy('wincount', 'desc')
      ->get();
```

However it's throwing the error

> QLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'digthetip.users.name' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: select count(status) as wincount, users.name from `tips` inner join `users` on `users`.`id` = `tips`.`user_id` where `tips`.`created_at` between 2016-11-01 00:00:00 and 2016-11-02 10:39:02 and `status` = Won group by `users`.`id` order by `wincount` desc)

but if I run the exact query the error has outputted into the SQL console within PHPMyAdmin the query runs fine and returns the results I require.

Am I missing something? I'm relatively new to Laravel and I'm massively confused how it's still throwing an error.

Comment: Can you post both SQL query's that you are comparing please?

Comment: You can use addSelect https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#selects
after join

Comment: The query I'm attempting to run is this

select count(status) as wincount, users.name from `tips` inner join `users` on `users`.`id` = `tips`.`user_id` where `tips`.`created_at` between '2016-11-01 00:00:00' and '2016-11-02 10:39:02' and `status` = 'Won' group by `users`.`id` order by `wincount` desc

Comment: Check https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/14997

Comment: What happens if you add the users.id in the select?

Comment: I think Sougatas comment shows the same issue as mine if I do a ->toSql() and run the query produced in pma console it runs fine but for some reason query builder throws an error.

Comment: Which Laravel version are you on?

Comment: @UmbertP. using users.id produces data with the users id and Laravel 5.3

Comment: I haven't worked with 5.3 yet, but seems like @SougataBose pointed on the right direction (the issue is closed , since August, though). I would suggest to go with the work arround of adding the column on the select for the time being if it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok so it turns out you can turn of SQL strict mode in /app/database.php which will prevent the error from happening.

'strict' => false,

Comment: It seems to me that is a bit of an overkill, when (by reading the docs http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sql-mode-strict, seems like a helpful thing to have activated).

As a last try, more as a curiosity now, what happens if you add 'IGNORE' on the raw sql `DB::raw('IGNORE count(status) as wincount` ?

Comment: This just throws the below error

IGNORE count(status) as wincount, users.name, users.id from `tips` inner join `u' at line 1 (SQL: select IGNORE count(status) as wincount, users.name, users.id from `tips` inner join `users` on `users`.`id` = `tips`.`user_id` where `tips`.`created_at` between 2016-11-01 00:00:00 and 2016-11-02 11:12:53 and `status` = Won group by `users`.`id` order by `wincount` desc

Comment: Thanks. I'll try to remember this for future wierd problems with my selects. Glad you solved it.

Comment: Yeah it's definitely inconvenient but I cant see any other way around it.

Comment: damn, if it wasn't for this thread i could've been searching for that one for a long time, thanks!